# collecting results asynchronously from gpars parallel executor

Tags: groovy, parallel-processing, fork-join, gpars

We've got some code in Java using ThreadPoolExecutor and CompletionService. Tasks are submitted in large batches to the pool; results go to the completion service where we collect completed tasks when available without waiting for the entire batch to complete:

```
 ThreadPoolExecutor _executorService =
            new ThreadPoolExecutor(MAX_NUMBER_OF_WORKERS, new LinkedBlockingQueue(20));
 CompletionService _completionService =
            new ExecutorCompletionService<Callable>(_executorService)

//submit tasks
_completionService.submit( some task);

//get results
while(...){
   Future result = _completionService.poll(timeout);
   if(result)
      //process result
}
```

The total number of workers in the pool is MAX_NUMBER_OF_WORKERS; tasks submitted without an available worker are queued; up to 20 tasks may be queued, after which, tasks are rejected.

**What is the [Gpars](http://gpars.codehaus.org/) counterpart to this approach?**

Reading the [documentation](http://gpars.org/SNAPSHOT/guide/guide/dataParallelism.html) on gpars parallelism, I found many potential options: `collectManyParallel()`, `anyParallel()`, `fork/join`, etc., and I'm not sure which ones to even test. I was hoping to find some mention of "completion" or "completion service" as a comparison in the docs, but found nothing. I'm looking for some direction/pointers on where to start from those experienced with gpars.

Answer (score 1):

Collecting results on-the-fly, throttling producers - this calls for a dataflow solution. Please find a sample runnable demo below:

```
import groovyx.gpars.dataflow.DataflowQueue
import groovyx.gpars.group.DefaultPGroup
import groovyx.gpars.scheduler.DefaultPool

import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

int MAX_NUMBER_OF_WORKERS = 10

ThreadPoolExecutor _executorService =
        new ThreadPoolExecutor(MAX_NUMBER_OF_WORKERS, MAX_NUMBER_OF_WORKERS, 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue(200));

final group = new DefaultPGroup(new DefaultPool(_executorService))
final results = new DataflowQueue()

//submit tasks
30.times {value ->
    group.task(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        void run() {
            println 'Starting ' + Thread.currentThread()
            sleep 5000
            println 'Finished ' + Thread.currentThread()
            results.bind(value)
        }
    });
}
group.task {
    results << -1  //stop the consumer eventually
}

//get results
while (true) {
    def result = results.val
    println result
    if (result == -1) break
    //process result
}

group.shutdown()
```